# ContentSizeFitter не обновляет объект после добавления дочернего объекта

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект WordBlock. На нем висит `VerticalLayoutGroup`, который вертикально размещает объектов-детей, и `ContentSizeFitter`, который подгоняет размер RectTransform под количество дочерних объектов.
Если говорить *просто*, то я хочу, чтобы при добавлении белых окошек `InputField` серый прямоугольник растягивался вниз.

**Однако** после создания объекта `SynonymBlock` из скрипта, серое окошко не изменяет размера, как будто не обновилось. Чтобы оно обновилось достаточно просто вручную отключить-включить объект, но это ***вручную***. Что нужно сделать, чтобы оно обновлялось и подгоняло размер само после созданию дочернего объекта?

> Скорее всего подобный вопрос уже был, но я его не нашел. Если есть, отметьте как дубликат, я посмотрю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Та оказался прав, `ContentSizeFitter` работает в паре с `LayoutGroup` и `LayoutElement`  на элементах группы. Документация полное говно, `ContentSizeFitter` не самостоятельный компонент, но о том как и с кем он взаимодействует ни слова. Теперь будем знать.

Comment: Прям очень заходит вешать на `Content` в `ScrollView`, когда там динамический список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось `ContentSizeFitter` работает по-другому, и он вообще не работает, вися на объекте LayoutElement.
Я решил задачу своим кодом.

```
[ExecuteAlways] // Чтобы размер подгонялся даже при редактировании (для удобства)
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
public class VerticalSizeFitter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int DefaultHeight; // Высота при отсутствии блоков
    [SerializeField] private int BlockHeight; // Высота блока
    [SerializeField] private Transform TargetParent; // Родитель блоков

    private RectTransform myRT;

    private void Awake()
    {
        myRT = GetComponent<RectTransform>(); // Кэшируем
    }

    public void Update ()
    {
        myRT.sizeDelta = new Vector2(myRT.sizeDelta.x, DefaultHeight + BlockHeight*TargetParent.childCount); // Задаем высоту
    }
```

Этот код полностью удовлетворяет моей задаче